# C# Delegates and method signatures

Tags: c#, delegates

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Any method that matches the delegate's
>   signature, which consists of the
>   return type and parameters, can be
>   assigned to the delegate.

So how is this possible:

```
public delegate void AlarmEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event AlarmEventHandler Alarm;

protected virtual void OnAlarm(EventArgs e)
        {
            AlarmEventHandler handler = Alarm;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                // Invokes the delegates.
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
```

delegate `AlarmEventHander` and event `AlarmEventHandler` have different signatures yet `handler` can be assigned to `Alarm`.

Perhaps I'm mis-understanding delegates somewhat, and I would be very grateful if someone could explain where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I think you have confused some of your symbol names.  In the code above, the delegate is called `AlarmEventHandler` and the event, which is of the same type, is called `Alarm`.  As they are of the same type, there is no problem with the assignment.  I think what is confusing you is the `OnAlarm` method which appears, perhaps, to be responding to a different event with a different delegate type.

Comment: See: Field-like events. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664455(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I don't see the problem here.  The types match exactly (both are `AlarmEventHandler`), so one would expect to be able to assign one to the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A delegate is like a class. An event is like a property. When you declare an `event` in a class, you declare the *type* of event it is. In this case, `AlarmEventHandler`, which is an *inner class* of the top-level class this is a part of.

In the `OnAlarm` method, you get the instance of the `AlarmEventHandler` class that has been assigned to the event, and invoke it.

To clear things up, your code above is similar to this, using normal classes & references:

```
public class InnerClass {
    public void MyMethod() { /* ... */ }
}

public InnerClass MyProperty { get; set; }

protected virtual void CallMyMethod() {
    InnerClass cls = MyProperty;
    if (cls != null)
        cls.MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: i like the way you explained it. it made me imagine how it works better

Answer (score 2):

Actually the signatures are the same. In .NET events are implemented with delegates.

```
public event AlarmEventHandler Alarm;
```

So above code is actually compiled by compiler as:

```
private AlarmEventHandler handler;

public event AlarmEventHandler Alarm
{
    add { handler += value; }
    remove { handler -= value; }
}
```

So event actually uses the same `AlarmEventHandler` delegate.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are mixing delegates and events. While events are dependant on delegates, they are difference concepts completly. So should be taken separately.
2. Delegate is like type definition. Place where you use this delegate is like variable or property.
3. Event makes this delegate behave differently from the outside. Signature is still same.

Answer (score 0):

An event is just a delegate. The delegate itselft can only be accessed from inside the class.
From the outside, only *add* and *remove* functionality for the event is possible to you can only do this:

```
myAlarm.Alarm+=new AlarmEventHandler(callPolice);
// or
myAlarm.Alarm-=new AlarmEventHandler(callPolice);
```

But from the inside of the class, Alarm is just a delegate of type AlarmEventHandler so you can do what your code shows:

```
        AlarmEventHandler handler = Alarm;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            // Invokes the delegates.
            handler(this, e);
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

A function which takes a base-class as (non reference) parameter can be converted to a delegate that takes a derived class as parameter. This is because the function that takes base can be safely substituted where-ever a function that takes a derived class is used.

```
void TakesObject(object o)
{
...
}

Action<string> myAction=TakesObject;
```

You can call myAction only by passing in a string. And since every string is an object the contract for TakesObject is fulfilled.

In your case is works because every `AlarmEventArgs` is an `EventArgs` too. So the contract requirements of your eventhandler are less strict than the contract guarantees of the delegate type used by the event.

This is called co- and contra-variance. You have co-variance in return-types, and contra variance in parameters.

Check this article on MSDN:
[Using Variance in Delegates (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174(v=VS.100).aspx)